# incompatible types how can i return the two values in java

Tags: java

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> longestConsecutiveIncreasingSequence(int[] arr) {
        /* Your class should be named Solution
         * Don't write main().
         * Don't read input, it is passed as function argument.
         * Return output and don't print it.
         * Taking input and printing output is handled automatically.
        */
        HashMap<Integer,Boolean>hm=new HashMap<>();
        for(int val :arr){
            hm.put(val,true);}
        for(int val:arr)
        {
           if( hm.containsKey(val-1))
            hm.put(val,false);
        }
        int msp=0;
        int ml=0;
        for (int val:arr) {
            if(hm.get(val)==true){
                int tsp=val;
                int tl=1;

                while(hm.containsKey(tsp+tl)){
                    tl++;}
                if(tl>ml){
                    ml=tl;;
                    msp=tsp; }
                 }
             }
        return (msp);
        return(msp+ml-1);
        
    }
```

Comment: Look the return type is `ArrayList<Integer>`  - maybe you could `add` to this `list`?

Comment: Actually what is the output you are expecting, here you are simply returning two integers while the return type is `ArrayList<Integer>`

Comment: i am hoping to return two integer values and I know the return type is  ArrayList<Integer>how can I return two numbers I mean how I can I return an array list with msp,(msp+ml-1) as elements

Comment: @RohithV He's returning zero integers since the code will not compile.

Comment: Off topic, but I'd recommend focusing on style a bit more. Doing that can even train your pattern recognition, preventing bugs. A style guide can help unify your code with what others produce, increasing your ability to understand other people's code. For example, `booleanValue == true` can be written as `booleanValue`. You have inconsistent indentation. Pick one like 2 or 4 spaces and stick with it. You have `val :arr` and `val:arr`. I'd recommend `val : arr` instead. You have `for(` and `for (`. Pick one and use it consistently. Use more descriptive variable names unlike `msp` and `ml`.

Comment: People generally also put spaces in between operators such as `t1 > m1` or `put(val, true)` or `msp + m1 - 1` or `hm = new`. Sometimes, people don't use spaces between operators that are multiplication-like with higher precedence such as `a*b` instead of `a * b` or `a%b` instead of `a % b`. Find a style guide and consistently use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
// use this syntax to add value in arraylist and then return list.  
ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();  
list.add(msp);  
list.add(msp+ml-1);  
return list
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return ArrayList. So, add both the values in Arraylist and then return arraylist.

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
al.add(msp);
al.add(msp + ml -1);
return al;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use type **org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair**
like this:

```
Pair<Integer, Integer> pair = new ImmutablePair<>(msp, msp+ml-1);
pair.getLeft();
pair.getRight();
```

Comment: The original poster is doing an algorithm puzzle problem for a website that mandates the method signature for use in their testing code. He can't change the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two return statements in a row like that. A function can only return a single value although you can have multiple return statements if they represent a single returned value based on logic such as:

```
if (a > 0)
    return "Positive";
else if (a == 0)
    return "Zero";
else // if (a < 0)
    return "Negative";
```

Here, you want to return a single `ArrayList<Integer>`. If you wanted the two values you said you want, it would look like:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(msp);  
arrayList.add(msp + ml - 1);  
return arrayList
```

This code creates a single new object on the heap that holds `Integer` object references contiguously in memory since it's an `ArrayList<Integer>`. Note, the actual `Integer` objects can be stored without being contiguous in memory. It then adds two `Integer` objects equal to the value in `msp` and the value of the result of the expression `msp + ml - 1`. A reference to this single `ArrayList<Integer>` is then returned. The single object itself can hold multiple `Integer` objects, which is why you can conceptually return more than one `Object` even though you can only ever return a single `Object`.

As for the logic in your program, based on the function name, it seems like you are supposed to return the sequence itself. Below is a way to do that:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> longestConsecutiveIncreasingSequence(int[] array) {
        if (array.length == 0)
            return new ArrayList<>();
        
        int max_sequence_length = 0;
        int max_sequence_start_index = 0;
        int current_sequence_start_index = 0;
        int current_sequence_length = 1;
        
        for (int index = 0; index < array.length; ++index) {
            if (index + 1 < array.length) {
                if (array[index] < array[index + 1]) {
                    ++current_sequence_length;
                } else {
                    if (max_sequence_length < current_sequence_length) {
                        max_sequence_length = current_sequence_length;
                        max_sequence_start_index = current_sequence_start_index;
                    }
                    current_sequence_start_index = index + 1;
                    current_sequence_length = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (max_sequence_length < current_sequence_length) {
            max_sequence_length = current_sequence_length;
            max_sequence_start_index = current_sequence_start_index;
        }
        
        ArrayList<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int index = max_sequence_start_index; index < max_sequence_start_index + max_sequence_length; ++index)
            sequence.add(array[index]);
        return sequence;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Single line code

`return Arrays.asList(msp,msp+ml-1);`